# hide sidebar menu in template html and JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to edit a template for my first web page and it has a responsive sidebar menu with sections home, contact,  etc. when I press each option the web page scrolls down to the desire section, but the menu stays there. How can I edit it so the menu keeps doing the same function but it disappears after clicked? I've tried to read the script file from the template and it is very complicated for me... this is  HTML part were the menu is :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header" >
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
<div class="navbar-collapse" style = "float: right;">
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" ><span aria-hidden="true" >&times;</span></button>
    
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"  >
        <li style ="font-weight: 500; font-size: 20px; font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;"  ><a href="./index.html#quienes-somos" title="Quienes-Somos" class="anchor-link" >¿Quiénes somos?  </a></li>
        <li style ="font-weight: 500; font-size: 20px; font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;" ><a href="./index.html#responsibilidad-section-container" title="Responsabilidad_social" class="anchor-link">Responsabilidad social</a></li>
        <li style ="font-weight: 500; font-size: 20px;font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;"  ><a href="./index.html#proyectos-section-container" title="Proyectos" class="anchor-link">Proyectos</a></li>
        <li style ="font-weight: 500; font-size: 20px;font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;" ><a href="./index.html#clientes-section-container" title="Clientes" class="anchor-link">Clientes</a></li>
        <li style ="font-weight: 500; font-size: 20px;font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;" ><a href="./index.html#contact-section-container" title="Contactanos" class="anchor-link">Contáctanos</a></li>


    </ul>
    
  </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

and I tried to add the script:

```
<script>
            $("nav li").click(function () {
        $(".navbar-right").hide();
         });
           </script>
```

as well as all the different classes of the ul (nav navbar-nav navbar-right) altogether and each individual and it doesn't work if someone could help me would be of great help. thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
         
         $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".close").click(function () {
        $(".navbar-right").hide();
         });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header" >
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
<div class="navbar-collapse" style = "float: right;">
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" ><span aria-hidden="true" >&times;</span></button>
    
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"  >
        <li style ="font-weight: 500; font-size: 20px; font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;"  ><a href="./index.html#quienes-somos" title="Quienes-Somos" class="anchor-link" >¿Quiénes somos?  </a></li>
        <li style ="font-weight: 500; font-size: 20px; font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;" ><a href="./index.html#responsibilidad-section-container" title="Responsabilidad_social" class="anchor-link">Responsabilidad social</a></li>
        <li style ="font-weight: 500; font-size: 20px;font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;"  ><a href="./index.html#proyectos-section-container" title="Proyectos" class="anchor-link">Proyectos</a></li>
        <li style ="font-weight: 500; font-size: 20px;font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;" ><a href="./index.html#clientes-section-container" title="Clientes" class="anchor-link">Clientes</a></li>
        <li style ="font-weight: 500; font-size: 20px;font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;" ><a href="./index.html#contact-section-container" title="Contactanos" class="anchor-link">Contáctanos</a></li>


    </ul>
    
  </div>
</div>
</nav>
```